# How to build a responsive website with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, reactjs, material-design

I am a bit confused. Until now I was using bootstrap or jquery mobile to build my application both base on jQuery. I heard a lot about ReactJs and I would like to use it for my next application. I am searching for something like bootstrap but purely written with ReactJs and ready to use. But until now I didn't found anything really convenient. First I was thinking to use MaterializeCss but I quickly realize that it was base as well on jQuery. There is material-ui purely written with ReactJs but there is no CDN and it oblige me to use third tool to build your app javascript files. Finally I found muicss but this one seem to be in a very early stage.

So till now I didn't found the right lib to build my app with ReactJs. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: There's no reason you can't use React with Bootstrap and JQuery. React is not really a "Framework" but more of a tool to help implement the Flux design pattern.

Comment: i think react is js and response is depending to css styles. I don't know any reason why you can't use them both.

Comment: But React is saying that it would be better to don't manipulate directly DOM. Or if you use jQuery or Bootstrap you do it!

Comment: @Alex lolwut? you can 100% write React without ever even thinking about Flux.

Comment: @Alexandre "responsive design" and React are orthogonal concerns!

Comment: @Mathletics I know, yes... it was built for Flux though...

Comment: @Alex no, it wasn't. Flux was designed after the fact as a way to share state between decoupled components (not to mention it's basically a straight-rip of the single-dispatcher pattern in Backbone.) React is just a way to quickly and _repeatably_ render a view. It doesn't care if you're writing an application or not.

Comment: I'm totally aware of the differences of React and Flux - however it's fair to say that Flux was designed with React in mind.

Comment: I think the first answer of Alex is very interesting. Now I understand that ReactJs alone is somehow useless... ReactJs just allow you to proceed the view in a component way and nothing else... Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Alex _Flux was designed with React in mind_ yes, absolutely; this is not the same as _[React] was built for Flux_!

Comment: @Mathletics of course, I thought we'd got that already? :)

Comment: @Alex not based on your previous comments, but if you got it, great :)

Comment: @Mathletics So just to be clear - in the beginning there was React.js - this was built for fast views. Then along came Flux which uses React to implement the design pattern. You claim that they stole this from Backbone - I don't think so, they are two completely different approaches. Care to clarify?

Comment: @Mathletics anyhow I think this is not the subject of my question... Even more Flux is just a concept...

Comment: IMO this thread should be open if and until it gets spammy. The conversation takes places regardless in a less informative manner.

Answer (score 34):

It all comes down to CSS.  Regardless of whether you are using vanilla CSS, SCSS, LESS, or CSS-in-JS, you're wanting to target your components with CSS selectors that allow you to adapt to resolution changes.

Here's a basic example:

```
// ./foo.js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

// Either as a Class
export default class FooClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="foo">Foo</div>;
  }
}

// Or as a function
export default FooFunction = (props) => <div className="foo">Foo</div>;
```

And in your styles.css:

```
.foo {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  /* Small Devices, Tablets */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: green;
  }

  /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
  @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

The styles above are applied in a mobile-first approach, meaning that the default class declaration is provided with how the element will look on the smallest screen targeted.  Those mobile styles will be overridden by the subsequent media queries. Over the years, these "inline" media queries directly under the CSS class have become my favorite way to organize my responsive styles.

Here are some responsive design resources:

https://css-tricks.com/nine-basic-principles-responsive-web-design/

[A comprehensive list of Media Queries](https://gist.github.com/robabby/255898e499a47b0ce67f)

Comment: this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive makes the job easy...Check it out...