# Why does my website look totally different on a cell phone (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've just completed my personal website that I've worked really hard on.  It looks normal on a computer but on a cellphone, it looks totally off.  Why's that?  This is my first website ever and I was super excited to see it on a phone only to see that it's completely discombobulated.

Here's my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>Website</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.css` file:

```
html {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.portfolio {
  text-align: center;
}

.about {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact {
  text-align: center;
}

.fullName {
  float: left;
}

.myPic {
  margin-left: -499px;
  height: 1051px;
}

.scrollTo {
  margin: inherit;
}

.number {
  font-size: 89px;
}

.email {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.githubIcon {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.masterPv:hover .pvPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.masterPv:hover .middlePv {
  opacity: 1;
}

.masterWFAFA:hover .WFAFAPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.masterWFAFA:hover .middleWFAFA {
  opacity: 1;
}

.masterHP:hover .HPPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.masterHP:hover .middleHP {
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrollToAbout {
  text-align: center;
}

.masterPv {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.pvPic {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middlePv {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pvText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;

  margin-right: 139px;
}

.masterWFAFA {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;


  /*top: -203px;*/


}

.WFAFAPic {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middleWFAFA {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.WFAFAText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  margin-right: 139px;
}

.masterHP {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 640px;
  bottom: 409px;
}

.HPPic {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middleHP {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.HPText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  margin-right: 139px;
}

.mainPic {
  border-width: 2px;
  width: 1100px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow:hidden;
}

code {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(134,321,342);
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 31px;
}
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var Website = React.createClass({

   scrolling: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".scrollToPortfolio").offset().top
        },'slow');
   },

   scrollToAbout: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".scrollToAbout").offset().top
     },'slow');
   },

   scrollToContact: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".scrollToContact").offset().top
     },'slow')
   },

  render: function() {

    return(

      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">my name</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.scrolling} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToAbout} type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToContact}type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>

        <div className="mainPic">
          <img src={"./pictures/skyline.jpg"}></img>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToPortfolio">
          <h2><u>Portfolio</u></h2>
          <div className="masterPv">
          <a href="http://piccolovillaggio.com/">
            <img src={"./pictures/portfolioPic1.png"} className="pvPic img-rounded"></img>
          </a>
             <div className="middlePv">
              <div className="pvText">Menu for catering company.</div>
             </div>
           </div>   

          <div className="masterWFAFA">
            <img src={"./pictures/WFAFA.png"} className="WFAFAPic img-rounded"></img>
              <div className="middleWFAFA">
                <div className="WFAFAText">Worlds first automated financial advisor.</div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div className="masterHP">
          <a href="http://www.ashikul.com/hunts-point/">
            <img src={"./pictures/HP.png"} className="HPPic img-rounded"></img>
          </a>
              <div className="middleHP">
                <div className="HPText">Hunts Point Seaport and Shipyard LLC company website.</div>
              </div>
          </div> 

          </div>

        <div className="scrollToAbout jumbotron">
          <h2><u>About</u></h2>
          <h2>Text Text Text Text</h2>
        </div>


        <div className="scrollToContact jumbotron">
          <h2><u>Contact</u></h2>
          <h1 className="number">3333333333</h1>
          <strong className="email"><a href="mailto:email@yahoo.com">email@yahoo.com</a></strong>
          <p>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-social-icon btn-lg btn-github githubIcon ">
             <span className="fa fa-github"></span>
           </a>
           </p>
        </div>

        <div className="wrapper"></div>
          <span>© 2017-2018 <b>my name</b></span>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Comment: For starters, your site is not responsive. Check more on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742532/how-to-build-a-responsive-website-with-reactjs).

Comment: @vasa Ah, I see.  I feel like it's because of various pixels that I've implemented which's causing it to look crazy on a cellphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Answer is it is because your website is not responsive**

First of all i'll consider this as your first complete project and that you are new to web designing. What your question is saying in summary is that **YOUR WEBSITE IS NOT RESPONSIVE**. For you to do this there are various means which a simple google search on responsive web designing would help.

To help your search you can search about plugins such as `bootstrap` for your responsive design or read on `css media queries`.

If we were to answer your question, it would be creating another website for you which is not what SO is for.

Ensure you read on `responsive-design`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the advice, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

"Discombobulated" isn't a very specific thing to diagnose. But overall I'd say your site looks wonky (on desktop AND mobile) because you've structured it in a... perplexing way. You're using Bootstrap for some things but not others, causing styles to clash and things to move out of alignment. For example you're using a `.container` but have no grid inside of it. Then you override critical Bootstrap styles like `margin` which throws everything off.

Bootstrap is a good framework to build upon, but if you're going to use it, use it properly. [Read the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), learn how the grid works, and build from that. Don't try to hand code so much stuff or override styles.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Installing bootstrap won't automagically make your webpage responsive.

Bootstrap grid system provides responsive design.
Here is an basic example of bootstrap grid system.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
   <div className="row">
      <div className="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

col class properties will add responsive style to your layout.

recently, I've used react-bootstrap for react projects and very happy with product, with react-bootstrap it's easier for developers to bootstrap your frontend more dynamically. here is

```
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Grid fluid={true}>
   <Row>
      <Col xs={12} md={6} mdOffset={3}></Col>
   </Row>
</Grid>
```