# Make a responsive menu in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am developing a single page in react and when I saw it on mobile version the menu organization was all messed up.
How can I put the menu responsive as I change from a pc version to a mobile version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a responsive website with ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742532/how-to-build-a-responsive-website-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is typically used to ***build responsive, mobile-first projects*** on the web. You can use bootstrap within a `React` project by downloading it with an: `npm i --save bootstrap`. Then downloading Bootstrap's dependencies: `popper.js`, and `JQuery`. After everything has been downloaded, within your React components, you could assign the appropriate Bootstrap classes to the semantic elements making up your components by using the `className` attribute.

However with that being said, perhaps an easier approach would be to utilize [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) since it's a "*React friendly version of bootstrap*". Directly from React-Bootstrap's documentation:

"*React bootstrap replaces the Bootstrap javascript. Each component has been built from scratch as true React components, without uneeded dependencies like jQuery. It's built with compatibility in mind, we embrace our bootstrap core and strive to be compatible with the world's largest UI ecosystem.*"

Here is an example [navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/), directly from their documentation, which would stack, as desired, when the device's screen size changes:

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
    </Form>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>;
```

Test it out on your end by enlarging and minimizing your browser window to see how the menu stacks and changes with different screen sizes.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React semantic ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/). There are lots of Ui components and all are responsive. Very easy to implement.